# Мой вопрос об отправке формы. Не отправляется форма обратной связи. Банально, но критично для меня.Что с этим делать?

Tags: javascript, php, html5, email

Такой просак, что сам не понимаю, что происходит.
Проблема такая: 
Есть файл ( sendemail.php )
Код: `

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
/* Устанавливаем e-mail Кому и от Кого будут приходить письма */   
$to = "Danila75kolokolov@yandex.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма   
$from = "info@kinokanikyli.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, от кого будут приходить письма, например no-reply(собака)epicblog.net

/* Указываем переменные, в которые будет записываться информация с формы */
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта КиноКаникулы";


/* Переменная, которая будет отправлена на почту со значениями, вводимых в поля */
$mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта! 
Имя отправителя: $first_name
Номер телефона: $phone
Текст сообщения: $message
Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";  

$headers = "From: $from \r\n";

/* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8')
    echo 'Отправлено';
}
else {
    echo 'Не отправлено';
};
echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
echo "<br /><br /><a href='http://cd17153.tmweb.ru/'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";
}
?>
<!--Переадресация на главную страницу сайта, через 3 секунды-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeurl(){eval(self.location="http://cd17153.tmweb.ru/");}
window.setTimeout("changeurl();",3000);
</script>
```

`
После этого эхом пишет "Не отправлено", значит mail() не выполняется.
Код формы:

```
<form action="sendemail.php" method="post" class="appointment-form ftco-animate">
                    <div class="d-md-flex">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-md-flex">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше сообщение (по необходимости)"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Были небольшие ошибки, типа лишней скобки, ну и headers вынес. Остальное всё правильно у Вас было.

```
<form action="sendemail.php" method="post" class="appointment-form ftco-animate">
    <div class="d-md-flex">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-flex">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше сообщение (по необходимости)"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    /* Устанавливаем e-mail Кому и от Кого будут приходить письма */
    $to = "Danila75kolokolov@yandex.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма
    $from = "info@kinokanikyli.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, от кого будут приходить письма, например no-reply(собака)epicblog.net

    /* Указываем переменные, в которые будет записываться информация с формы */
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта КиноКаникулы";


    /* Переменная, которая будет отправлена на почту со значениями, вводимых в поля */
    $mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта! 
Имя отправителя: $first_name
Номер телефона: $phone
Текст сообщения: $message
Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n"; //Если надо именно utf-8 - менять тут.
    $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $to\r\n";

    /* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers);
    echo 'Отправлено';
}
else {
    echo 'Не отправлено';
};
    echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href='http://cd17153.tmweb.ru/'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";

?>
<!--Переадресация на главную страницу сайта, через 3 секунды-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeurl(){eval(self.location="http://cd17153.tmweb.ru/");}
    window.setTimeout("changeurl();",3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все верно.
А еще таймвеб на временном домене запрещает функцию mail(), поэтому при переносе на платный аккаунт все сработало